# How to create a Job for Merge Replication?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to create a **step in a Job** for Merge Replication. I basically want to know which command should I write so that a particular Subscription starts synchronizing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your replication, it will automatically create a job with all of the steps needed for replication if you use the GUI.

Step 1: Merge Agent Startup Message. Type T-SQL ran on the distribution database

Step 2: Run Agent. Type Replication Merge. The command will be something like:
-Publisher [] -PublisherDB [] -Publication [] -Subscriber [] -SubscriberDB []   -Distributor [] -DistributorSecurityMode 1

Step 3: Detect nonlogged agent shutdown. Type T-SQL sp_MSDetect_nonlogged_shutdown @ subsystem='Merge', @agentid=